# Display Array List on JSP with tab-spacing?

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

Hey guys I'm trying to display a `ArrayList` onto a JSP page. When a string is added to this list, a tab spacing is also added using `"\t"` however when I print this List onto the JSP page using script-let tags there is no **tab** spacing. I know `JSTL` is a better method to achieve this but I'm required to use script-lets.

Java code:

```js
public getSchedule() {
    scdList.add("CRN" + "\t" + "Course-ID" + "\t" + "Time-Days" + "\t" + "Room-Number" + "\t" + "Instructor");
    scdList.add(CRN + "\t" + CourseID + "\t" + TimeDays + "\t" + RoomNo + "\t" + Instructor);
}
```

JSP page:

```js
<table style="width:750px" border="5">
<%
  StudentSchedule sc1 = new StudentSchedule();
  sc1.getSchedule();
  for (int i = 0; i < sc1.scdList.size(); i++) {
%>
<tr>
   <td align="center"><%= sc1.scdList.get(i) %></td>
<%
}
%>
</tr>
</table>
```

And here is the result:

CRN Course-ID   Time-Days   Room-Number Instructor

31107   CIST 1510   TTH1-5pm    F1149   6

30109   CIST 2371   TTH1-5pm    F1147   3

30103   CIST 1130   TTH6-9pm    F1145   2